# Logging Azure CosmosDB using Azure Storage Account

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Is this possible to send Azure CosmosDB logs to some storage account in Azure? I could not find any much info there??

Comment: What logs are you referring to? The Change Feed?

Comment: When I say Logs of Azure Cosmos DB, it means Info/Warning/Error Logs which I get in activity console. A very basic example will be a new connection request to the DB which I want to track down. Dont know what is unclear here for which the question has been marked down :/

Comment: Do you have any update about this thread? If it is useful, please mark it that will help more communities who have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Currently,it seems it is not supported with Azure portal. If program is possible, we could do that with [Azure Monitor REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/activity-logs).

[image]

Then we could write the activity log to the Azure storage with Azure storage [Put blob API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob). I also find a [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42808234/accessing-azure-blob-storage-using-rest-api) about how to access using Azure Blob Storage Using Rest API.